# 'this' parameter is being passed implicitly when a non-static/instance method is called - java

Tags: java

I read a statement that the keyword 'this' is being passed implicitly when a instance method calls another instance method of the same/another class.

Does it mean it look like:

```
class A {
    void method1() {
        this.method2(this);
        // where 'this' is implicitly passed and the actual
        // code looks like **this.method2();**
    }

    void method2() {
    }
}
```

Are there any document that supports this statement? or a discussion in regards to this topic?

Comment: `this` is not exactly "passed". Any basic Java tutorial will cover `this`.

Comment: you mean by "exactly passed" is that the developer didn't write the word 'this' right?

Comment: That's not "passing this", it's "calling a method on this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a non-static method on an object:

```
object.method();
```

it is implicitly converted to

```
method(object);
```

and the value of `object` becomes `this` inside the method.

Comment: so it is the same as "this.method()" will be converted to "method(object") implicitly, right?

Comment: No, it is converted to `method(this)`, but that's a degenerate case. I was answering for the general case.